# How do I attach a link to a button properly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to attach link to a button that will open when clicked.

```
from Tkinter import *
import webbrowser

class Window(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):  

        self.master.title("Anonymous Button Box")    

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)  

        _Button = Button(self, text="Don't Click", command=webbrowser.open("http://example.com", new=2, autoraise="True"))  

        _Click = Button(self, text="Click") 

        _Click.place(x=80, y=0)  

        _Button.place(x=0, y=0)  



root = Tk()

root.geometry("300x300")        

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this it automatically opens the link before the box itself pops up. How would I write it so the link only runs when the button is pressed?
would I create another function to open the link then command it to use the function when button is pressed?

Comment: write a function that opens the link in browser, lets call it `open_link()`. Change your code to this `command= self.open_link` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, a button command should call a function that accepts no parameters.  By doing this, it becomes easier to write the command, to create the button, and to debug the program.

So, in this case I would create a function named something like `open_browser`, or`on_dont_click_button`, or something like that:

```
def open_browser(self):
    webbrowser.open("http://example.com", new=2, autoraise="True")
```

Then, the button becomes much easier to implement:

```
_Button = Button(..., command=open_browser, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the button command in a `lambda` function. So my button looks like this:

```
`_Button = Button(self, text="Don't Click", command=lambda: webbrowser.open("http://example.com", new=2, autoraise="True"))`
```